# A unique key for a two dimensional array of letters

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

I have a two dimensional array of letters. Any letter can vary according to a certain alphabet. 
I want to make a unique key for this array according to the letters and its position.
 For example, if the array is 3 * 3 and the alphabet is {0, a, b, c, *}, the array can be in the form like:

```
0 b c
b * a
a a 0
```

I have tried `Key = sum(code(letter)*(r*3+c))` for all r and c, where r and c are the row and the column, but it still gives me the same key for different array forms.

What do I miss?

P.S. `code(letter)` is a mapping function to convert the letter into a value.

Comment: Do you really have to get a unique key? Why don't you use a hash table, which allows collisions?

Comment: This is a good choice, I can think of it if the idea of unique key is not feasible.

Answer (score 3):

You need to take into account the size of alphabet. If code and indices are all zero based it would be:

```
key = Sum(code(letter)*pow(L, r*C+c))
```

where L is the number of letters and C is the number of columns. However watch out for numeric overflow. For larger alphabets or matrices you need to use one of the following:

- Lessen the requirement of keys being unique and use a hash (hash combiner).
- Larger number type for the key or even unlimited arithmetic type such as in [GMP lib](https://gmplib.org/).
- Compression such as [arithmetic coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding) if the distribution of letters is not even. However you still run into the risk of not being able to fit / compress specific matrix into the key.

Comment: This is perfect, but this can be used only for a small Alphabet, and small arrays. If Alphabet is more than 20 characters, and the array is larger than 5*5 then I can't use this function.

Comment: @NagyFathy if you want to assign unique numbers to objects in a set with billions of billions of members, you're going to need to deal with large numbers; there's no way around that. As a commenter asks, do you really need a unique number for every different instance?

Comment: This unique key is much faster in my application, but I can try hash table and check the performance.